# Visualization of a step in the proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

In a proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem, one has the following construction:

> Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $f\in C_c(X,[0,1])$. Define open sets for fixed $n$
>   $$
> G_j=\left\{x\in X: f(x)>\frac{j-1}{n}\right\}, j=1,2,\cdots, n, n+1
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> f_j(x)=\begin{cases}
> 0,&  x\not\in G_j\\
> \min\{nf(x)-j-1,j\},&  x\in G_j
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   We have then 
>   $$
> f=\frac{1}{n}(f_1+f_2+\cdots+f_n)$$ 
>   and 
>   $$1_{\overline{G_{j+1}}}\leq f_j\leq 1_{G_j}
> $$

What is the intuition of the definition of $f_j$?

Comment: It may be a little easier to picture $\frac{1}{n} f_j$.  I think it will be instructive for you to draw a picture for  yourself.  Sketch some continuous function $f$, like maybe $1-x^2$ (cut off outside $[-1,1]$), take $n=4$ for instance, and sketch the $f_j$.  It will help to draw horizontal lines at $1/4, 2/4, 3/4$.  It will also help to visualize $\frac{1}{n} (f_1 + \dots + f_j)$ as "stacking up" the functions $\frac{1}{n} f_j$.

Comment: mathematica `n = 10; k[y_] := (1 - y^2) UnitBox[y/2]; gs = 
 Join[{-1}, 
  x /. First@Solve[k[x] == (# - 1)/n, x] & /@ Range[2, n] // 
   Quiet, {0}];
f[j_Integer, x_] := 0 /; Abs[x] > Abs[gs[[j]]];
f[j_Integer, x_] := Min[n k[x] - j - 1, j] /; Abs[x] <= Abs[gs[[j]]];
Plot[f[#, x] & /@ Range@n, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]`  Result : http://i.stack.imgur.com/59nNR.png